# ORACLE SQL: Returning only non primary account holders who joined later or from different channel from primary?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data, where each account id can have multiple members associated with it

```
ACCOUNT_ID  MEMBER_ENROLL_DTE   PRIMARY_FLG ENROLL_CHANNEL_ID                       
3021            3/22/2011           1           50
3022            3/23/2011           1           50
3022            1/2/2013            0           50
3023            3/23/2011           1           50
3024            3/23/2011           1           52
3025            3/23/2011           1           52
3025            3/23/2011           0           48
3026            3/23/2011           1           52
3026            3/23/2011           0           52
```

I'm trying to do the following:
Wherever there's multiple members in the same account, return these records if either the enroll date, or the enroll channel are different.

That is I want to partition by account_id, then order by enrollment date, enrollment channel, and primary_flg, and then return records with primary flag set to 0 and the date and channel differs from the primary account holder (PRIMARY_FLG = 1). In this case I would get two records back

```
ACCOUNT_ID  MEMBER_ENROLL_DTE   PRIMARY_FLG ENROLL_CHANNEL_ID                        
3022            1/2/2013            0           50      
3025            3/23/2011           0           48
```

I'm mostly hung up on how to do the condition that the enroll date or enroll channel differ. I'm able to get all non primaries by doing the following

```
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT t.*,
         LAG( CASE "Primary" WHEN 1 THEN 1 END ) IGNORE NULLS
           OVER ( PARTITION BY account_id ORDER BY MEMBER_ENROLL_DTE, PRIMARY_FLG, ENROLL_CHANNEL_ID )
           AS has_prev_primary
  FROM   table_name t
)
WHERE  has_prev_primary = 1;
```

I think this may even do what I want it to do but I'm not 100% sure - it seems to not return members who joined the same day, but I'm not sure why. can someone suggest necessary changes?

Comment: Could you explain what is `the primary account holder` ? How do you know that a given record represents the primary accond holder while others don't ?

Comment: Hi that is the PRIMARY_FLG - I'll make it clearer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Original answer gets all entries for an account ID where there was a mismatch. This seems more useful to me in many contexts.

```
SELECT t.account_id, t.primary_flg, t.member_enroll_dte, t.enroll_channel_id
FROM table_name t
WHERE t.account_id IN (
    SELECT account_id
    FROM table_name t2
    GROUP BY account_id
    HAVING min(primary_flg) != max(primary_flg)
    AND NOT (
        min(member_enroll_dte) = max(member_enroll_dte) AND
        min(enroll_channel_id) = max(enroll_channel_id)
    )
)
ORDER BY 1,2 desc,3,4;
```

---

Alternative answer will just give you the non-primary records that don't match and nothing else.

```
SELECT t.account_id, t.primary_flg, t.member_enroll_dte, t.enroll_channel_id
FROM table_name t
WHERE t.primary_flg = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM table_name t_sub
    WHERE t_sub.account_id = t.account_id
    AND t_sub.primary_flg = 1
    AND t_sub.member_enroll_date = t.member_enroll_date
    AND t_sub.enroll_channel_id = t.enroll_channel_id )
ORDER BY 1,3,4
```

---

Try this for the query you mentioned in comments where non-primary should come after the primary.

```
SELECT t.account_id, t.primary_flg, t.member_enroll_dte, t.enroll_channel_id
FROM table_name t
WHERE t.primary_flg = 0
AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT null
    FROM table_name t_sub
    WHERE t_sub.account_id = t.account_id
    AND t_sub.primary_flg = 1
    AND t_sub.enroll_channel_id = t.enroll_channel_id
    AND t_sub.member_enroll_date >= t.member_enroll_date )
ORDER BY 1,3,4
```

Comment: Hmm I see both primary members as well as non-primary with the same enroll date/channel as the primary come in on this

Comment: Edited. Didn't notice the other answer until just now.

Comment: Thanks that works great. Only issue I'm having now is that occasionally the primary is listed as enrolled AFTER the non-primary (which would be a data issue). How can I add the condition to only include non-primaries with an enroll date greater than the primary? I tried just adding "AND t_sub.MEMBER_ENROLL_DTE > t.MEMBER_ENROLL_DTE" but that got me weird results...

Comment: I edited the answer to include a separate query for that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
select * from table1 t1
where primary_flg = 0
  and NOT exists (
     select 123 + 786 from table1 t2
     where t1.account_id = t1.account_id
       and t2.primary_flg = 1
       and t2.member_enroll_dte = t1.member_enroll_dte
       and t2.ENROLL_CHANNEL_ID = t1.ENROLL_CHANNEL_ID
)
```